# Error: Google font file error and the error message

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-dependencies, google-fonts

When running flutter google fonts dosent load. And this error shows up.

Failed to load font with url https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/a/62d4580d4d42de39d74b4087814e559b5480f30604b8d5d2929f391cda48adda.ttf: ClientException with SocketException: Failed host lookup: 'fonts.gstatic.com' (OS Error: No address associated with hostname, errno = 7), uri=https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/a/62d4580d4d42de39d74b4087814e559b5480f30604b8d5d2929f391cda48adda.ttf

And when running the code in debug mode the google_fonts_base.dart file opens up as in the picture and when hovering on the yellow arrow. It says unverified breakpoint.

How do i solve this.

Comment: Does this happen in Android/iOS/web/simulator? Did you configure your app to allow internet access on the device?